# Fetch data from database to display in a listview using Parse.com

Tags: java, android, database, listview, parse-platform

I want to display specific data in a listview from a database's column using parse.com, i just don't know how to specifically do that,following is the code there is an error here but you can change it completely to solve it !

public class Donar_Acceptor_list extends ListActivity {

```
// Declare Variables
ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
```

// ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from listview_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.donar_acceptor_list);
    // Execute RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
   // new RemoteDataTask().execute();
}

protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) throws com.parse.ParseException {
        // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("DonAcc");
        query.whereEqualTo("DonAcc", "donar");
       // ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
        //        "username");
        query.orderByDescending("_created_at");
        try {
            ob = query.find();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        // Pass the results into an ArrayAdapter
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Donar_Acceptor_list.this,
                R.layout.donar_aceptor_discription);
        // Retrieve object "name" from Parse.com database
        for (ParseObject status : ob) {
            adapter.add((String) status.get("name"));
        } 
       listview.setAdapter(adapter); } }
```

Comment: Check my answer there to have the full procedure : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26892496/4232337

Comment: Thanks but can you provide me a code for this? As i'm a newbie and it could be stupid but i'll be really thankful if you do.

Comment: The link I provide in the other solution gives you plenty of code explained. I'm sure you'll be able to understand it easily and adapt it to your particular solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821759/nullpointerexception-at-android-widget-arrayadapter-createviewfromresource

I have made it more clear here!

Answer (score 1):

First you dont need to use asyncTask' `doInBackground` to execute your query. You can use Parse's [findInBackground](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries) method to find objects asynchronously in the background without blocking your main UI thread.

Second, not sure why you use `ParseQuery.getQuery("DonAcc");`, if you try to get the data from the table name "Country". So you should use `ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Country");`

Third, you are using the listView as a member variable, so your class doesnt need to extends the listActivity, instead, it should just extends the regular Activity. So, you should do `public class Donar_Acceptor_list extends Activity`

So you can change your code to the following:

```
private void findName() {
       listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Country");
        query.whereEqualTo("DonAcc", "donar"); //assume you have a DonAcc column in your Country table
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt"); //Parse has a built createAt
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> nameList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (ParseObject object: nameList) {
                    String name = object.getString("name"); //assume you have a name column in your Country table
                    myList.add(name);
                }
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Donar_Acceptor_list.this,
                    R.layout.donar_aceptor_discription, myList);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                Log.d("error", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

You can probably call this method in your onCreate() method. Not sure what your `Donar_Acceptor_list` and `R.layout.donar_aceptor_discription` actually are, so the above code might not compile, but the idea is to use Parse's `findInBackground()` method instead of using `asynctask`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821759/nullpointerexception-at-android-widget-arrayadapter-createviewfromresource

please check this i have made it more clear and specific